# Jenkins Grails plugin error - grails doesn't exist

Tags: grails, jenkins

I am running jenkins 1.551 as a service on ubuntu 12.04. I have installed the grails plugin version 1.7. I had to install it manually since jenkins was unable to contact the update centre presumably because of a reverse proxy error(I saw a warning message for it). I installed grails 2.3.4 using gvm tool. Now when I initiate the build process it fails instantly throwing

`FATAL: /root/.gvm/grails/2.3.4/bin/grails doesn't exist
Build step 'Build With Grails' marked build as failure`

even though the grails script exists there with full executable permissions.
I tried installing an older version of the plugin(1.5) but still no help.

Is the above happening because I haven't installed the plugins from the update centre site? or is it a bug in the plugin?

To rule out any possible permission errors I have added jenkins to /etc/sudoers which I know is far from ideal.

Comment: I ended up deploying jenkins as a war file on tomcat where it was able to install plugins from the update center. When I installed the grails plugin from the update center no errors were shown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Grails binary had 755 permission  but the same was not applicable to the parent directories.
The user running Tomcat (tomcat) was not able to access the directories holding Grails binary

I did a chmod 755  for the directories and this helped resolved the issue.

There is no need to put the user  in /etc/sudoers. I dont think   sudo  permissions will ever be used.